# looking for faucet API so i could use it for tests - Automated faucet

Tags: bitcoin-core, api, testnet, faucets, automation

i would like to make some tests on test net, the issue is every time i have insufficient fund in my wallet i need to find a faucet and manually add funds.
i would like to create an automatic faucet that will fill the balance in my wallet, I've found an Ether faucet API in GitHub, and i'll really appreciate if anyone could help me with finding bitcoin API.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `regtest`, the regression testing network, not `testnet`. Results using it are reliable and repeatable,  most importantly don’t rely on the will of others.